# Data explorer not rendering result

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am new to MS Azure earlier my query were working but,now not able to execute the same query in azure data explorer

**sample Query**

```
StormEvents
| take 5
| project StartTime, EndTime, State, EventType, DamageProperty, EpisodeNarrative
```

Comment: Sunny, "not able to execute" is not a professional observation. Is the execution button disabled? Did you get an error message? Did your computer burst into flames? Having said that, since you seem to use the public shared `help` cluster which is up and running, and since your query can be executed successfully As Is - you probably didn't choose the `Samples` database. You can do it by clicking on it in the objects explorer on the left side of the ADX web explorer or by using the following link which includes the cluster & database https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As shown in below screenshot, Check if cluster is started or stopped.

If status is Stopped, you will not able to access data using queries and you can not ingest data.

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-cluster-database-portal